# Linear operator and compositions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space of arbitrary dimension, $a\in\mathbb{K}\setminus\{0\}$ and $u\in\mathcal{L}(E)$ an endomorphism of $E$ satisfying the following equation $$a^2u-3au^2+u^3=0_{\mathcal{L}(E)}.$$ Show that $E=\ker(u)\bigoplus Im(u)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proving that $\mathbf{\operatorname{Ker}(u)\cap\operatorname{Im}(u)=\{0\}}$:**

If $y\in \operatorname{Im}(u)$, then $y=u(x)$ for some $x\in E$. Assume that $y\in\operatorname{Ker}(u)$. This is, $0=u(y)=u^2(x)$. Then $0=(a^2-3au^2+u^3)(x)=a^2u(x)=a^2y$. Therefore $\operatorname{Ker}(u)\cap\operatorname{Im}(u)=\{0\}$.

**Proving that $\mathbf{E\subseteq \operatorname{Im}(u)\oplus\operatorname{Ker}(u)}$:**

Consider the polynomials $P(t)=t^2-3at+a^2$ and $Q(t)=t$. They are relatively prime. Therefore, there are polynomials $M,N$ such that

$$P(t)M(t)+Q(t)N(t)=1$$

Evaluating this equation in $u$ and applying it to an arbitrary element $x\in E$, we get $$P(u)M(u)(x)+Q(u)N(u)(x)=(x)$$

Therefore, $x$ is the sum of an element of $\operatorname{Im}(u)$, which is $Q(u)N(u)(x)=uN(u)(x)$ and an element of $\operatorname{Ker}(u)$, which is the other term $P(u)M(u)(x)=(a^2-3au+u^2)M(u)(x)$.